# Excel - Use of MAXIFS (in excel 2010)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, ifs, maxifs

I want to solve a stock problem. I have stock from some articles in a specific store and I want to find out which store in the same country has the highest stock of this specific item.

I use the table below for information input

[image]

Column A: Article number

Column B: Country

Column C: Stock

Column D: Store number

For instance:

I would like to know for article 884 in Netherlands, which store has the highest stock. The outcome would be store 1.

I'm not able to use the formulas MAXIFS :(.

Is there a possibility to work around and get the same answer?

Comment: You can simply use `MAX` and `IF` in an array for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst you could do as per my comment using `MAX` and `IF` in an array (also see [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/maximum-if-multiple-criteria) page for some additional information), you can also try the following:

[image]

Formula in `G3`:

```
=INDEX(D2:D7,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A7=G1)*(B2:B7=G2)*(C2:C7=MAX(INDEX((A2:A7=G1)*(B2:B7=G2)*(C2:C7),))),),0))
```

Or in Dutch (I assume you are)

```
=INDEX(D2:D7;VERGELIJKEN(1;INDEX((A2:A7=G1)*(B2:B7=G2)*(C2:C7=MAX(INDEX((A2:A7=G1)*(B2:B7=G2)*(C2:C7);))););0))
```

Comment: INDEX and MAX are named the same in Dutch? Learned something new today.

Comment: Cool approach, I like the combination of MAX and INDEX, something new for me to learn.

Comment: @JustynaMK, your approach isn't much different (hence the upvote)

Comment: @JustynaMK and JvdV thank you for your help. It will really help me out

Comment: @woutergroeneweg, glad it helped. If this has answered than pls upvote/accept the answer but clicking the checkmark on the left to return the favour (upvoting can be done to any post you found helpful)

Comment: @JvdV It doesn't work with A:A for example, is there a simple solution for this? I use it now as A2:A6000 for instance

Comment: You really don't want to use whole column references @WouterGroeneweg. Instead you can try: `A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))` and do the same for the other ranges.

Comment: @JvdV That is a new combination it did not know before.  The code works only if the highest number has not already been 'seen' in the row .  I set your formule in row E and drag it down but it's is not working. Do you know why it's not working?
 `=INDEX(D2:INDEX(D:D;AANTALARG(D:D));VERGELIJKEN(1;INDEX((A2:INDEX(A:A;AANTALARG(A:A))=A2)*(B2:INDEX(B:B;AANTALARG(B:B))=B2)*(C2:INDEX(C:C;AANTALARG(C:C))=MAX(INDEX((A2:INDEX(A:A;AANTALARG(A:A))=A2)*(B2:INDEX(B:B;AANTALARG(B:B))=B2)*(C2:INDEX(C:C;AANTALARG(C:C)));))););0))`

Comment: @WouterGroeneweg, in the sample data above: the formula would be: `=INDEX(D:D;VERGELIJKEN(1;INDEX((A2:INDEX(A:A;AANTALARG(A:A))=G1)*(B2:INDEX(B:B;AANTALARG(B:B))=G2)*(C2:INDEX(C:C;AANTALARG(C:C))=MAX(INDEX((A2:INDEX(A:A;AANTALARG(A:A))=G1)*(B2:INDEX(B:B;AANTALARG(B:B))=G2)*(C2:INDEX(C:C;AANTALARG(C:C)));))););0)+1)`. We assume there are no empty cells in your matrix (or the formula will return false info)

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling there's a much simpler solution to that, but... here it goes...

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$7,SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(MAX(--($A$2:$A$7=A10)*--($B$2:$B$7=B10)*$C$2:$C$7),--($A$2:$A$7=A10)*--($B$2:$B$7=B10)*$C$2:$C$7,0)))
```

[image]