# Select a column if Max Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Assuming I have data:

```
Data 1           Data 2    Data 3
Sleep            Hotel     2019-10-01
Throw Rubbish    Hotel     2019-10-03
Do Errands       Hotel     2019-10-02
```

How do I dynamically select Data 1 when Data 3 is the max value?

In this case, I'd like the column to have "Throw Rubbish" if Data 2 is "Hotel" and Data 3 is max.

Comment: Would you like Excel to actually select `Throw Rubbish` cell for you, or do you simply need an Excel formula that will return the value of `Throw Rubbish`, based on your conditions?

Comment: Its done through some, `INDEX`, `MATCH` and `MAX`. I believe we had a similar issue just a day ago. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59054692/9758194). You would just need one criteria less =)

Comment: **Sidenote**: You have a *huge* amount of open question. It's only decent to revisit them and where possible credit the people that helped you out. Upvote those answers that you found valuable, and accept those that have answered your questions. That would return the favor in the form of exp. points plus it would close all your open threads.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, it's done through a mix of `INDEX`, `MATCH` and `MAX`. For example

[image]

Formula in `F1`:

```
=INDEX(A2:A4,MATCH(1,INDEX((B2:B4=F2)*(C2:C4=MAX(INDEX((B2:B4=F2)*(C2:C4),))),),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AGGREGATE with INDEX():

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(B2:B4)/((AGGREGATE(14,7,C2:C4/(B2:B4="Hotel"),1)=C2:C4)*(B2:B4="Hotel")),1))
```